# Magento 2.2.5 Product details blank page while switching to Production mode

Tags: magento2, product, production-mode

My magento site when setting to Prod mode displays blank Product detail page. The page is perfect in developer mode though.

Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/qmt3db

I ran the following while changing the mode.
`bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`

After that,

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

I also tried reindexing the files, but none of my efforts to fix this worked and I had to revert as I was playing with Live site.

I have a feeling reading other forums that some extensions may be causing this to happen; but I am still puzzled whether this is correct or not. My list of extensions are as follows:

- Aheadworks Coupongenerator
- Aheadworks Followupemail2
- Aheadworks OnSale
- Magefan Blog
- Mageplaza One step checkout
- Magesales Auspost
- MageWorx OrderEditor
- Sm Zumi
- Sm ShopBy
- Sm SearchBox
- Sm MegaMenu
- Sm ListingTabs
- Sm InstagramGallery
- Sm FilterProducts
- Sm Categories
- Sm CartQuickPro
- Sm BackEnd
- Eway payment

Please provide your suggestions on how I may be able to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked in log files for error?

Comment: on line 14 of app/bootstrap.php change #ini_set('display_errors', 1); to ini_set('display_errors', 1); this will display the error on the page giving you more clarity on what the issue may be. if you still have issues understanding the error . update your question and we will be able to help further

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the error logs and found out that it was my template which was giving the error. The template was bought one.

So, upon my research, I found out that to solve this, you will first need to check whether your template is giving the error, or the extensions that have been installed is generating it. It is very unlikely that you will find the solution to this by googling as it mostly depends on what you have used.

Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Since you found a solution maybe mark your question as answered, so it doesn't stay opened